# NSPredicate fetch other entities using an entity's relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Alright, here is a piece of my model:

[image]

I have a TableViewController which is being populated using a NSFetchedResultsController. In the TableViewController, **I want to display all Songs that are a part of a specific playlist.** I was hoping to achieve this by somehow fetching all Songs entities that the playlistSongs relationship points to. This TableViewController has a reference a playlist object (although I doubt that will help me here).

My difficulty has been setting up the predicate.

```
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Playlist"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(self.playlistSongs)"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you want to display Songs then you have to create a fetch request
on the "Song" entity:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Song"];
```

To restrict the result to the songs of a given playlist, use the relationship from "Song"
to "Playlist". This is a *to-many* relationship, so you have to specify "ANY":

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY playListIAmIn == %@", selectedPlaylist];
```

Comment: I have a one-to-many relationship and didn't need `"ANY"`. Why could that be?